# My flutter app not run on iPhone 11 Xcode 14 pod not installed how to fix this problem?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, cocoapods

My flutter app runs perfect on android device but on trying to launch on ios device, it runs the pod install  command forever.

Run flutter app on ios device.

I run many command but still this problem not fixed. I created new project but same problem why I face this problem please give me any working solution.